# Dockerfile ..... ✖ Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c autoreconf -ivf /bin/sh: autoreconf: not found

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, pm2

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/salvator/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/$

WORKDIR /home/node/salvator

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "pm2 start", "index.js" ]
```

I am cloning the app repository from bitbucket and i cant understand what do ineed to write in place of WORKDIR and RUN mkdir

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. One of your dependency relies on `autoreconf`. So you need to install it before running `npm install`.

Comment: which package do i need to install

Answer (score 15):

`autoconf` is a dependency you're looking for.
*note: it's not called `autoreconf`.*

```
RUN apk add --no-cache autoconf
```

then you will be able to use `autoreconf` without issues.